# Prettier 3.0.0 TypeError: prettier.resolveConfig.sync is not a function

Tags: eslint, prettier

The error triggered after I run this command:

```
npx eslint "the code directory"
```

This is the first several line of the error

```
TypeError: prettier.resolveConfig.sync is not a function
Occurred while linting *the first line of the first code directory*  
Rule: "prettier/prettier"
    at Program (*the main directory*\node_modules\eslint-plugin-prettier\eslint-plugin-prettier.js:138:40)
```

These are eslint, prettier, and the other config taken from package.json

```
"eslint": "^8.42.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
"eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.13.3",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
"prettier": "3.0.0",
"prettier-eslint": "^15.0.1"
```

I've tried delete the files from node_modules and run 'npm i' then restart the IDE (using VS Code), it still happens.

Comment: The resolveConfig functionality got removed with the release of Prettier v3: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/pull/12788 - This was a breaking change, so tooling relying on this functionality need to upgrade as well. Workaround: Downgrade to Prettier v2.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

There is an incompatibility between `prettier` 3 and `eslint-plugin-prettier` 4.

You can fix this by using version 5 of `eslint-plugin-prettier`:

```bash
yarn add -D eslint-plugin-prettier@5.0.0
```

or

```bash
npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-prettier@5.0.0
```

- Official issue: https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier/issues/562
- v5 release notes: https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier/releases/tag/v5.0.0

Comment: Using eslint-plugin-prettier alpha and prettier ^3.0.0 breaks the formatting feature from prettier. If we see in 'Format document with...' section, there are so many ESLint listed. Option + Shift + F is also not working. Reverting back to eslint-plugin-prettier ^4.2.1 and prettier ^2.8.8 makes formatting working again.

Comment: The version 5 its not in alpha anymore! =)

Comment: Works, thank you!
or 
`pnpm add -D eslint-plugin-prettier@latest --save-exact`

Comment: `stylelint-prettier@3.x.x` and below will not work with prettier v3. You will also need to bump that package to 4.0.0.

Comment: It worth to mention that it seems like `eslint-plugin-prettier` is now a mandatory dependency, which is not updated automatically as peer dependency forcing us to install it explicitly even when it previously not used in a project. Anyway, it helped me too, thanks.

Comment: Agree with @IgorNikiforov.
Also worked for me (upgrading from 2.8.8 to 3.0.3)

Comment: for me it was neccessary also add

"npm install @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@latest --save-dev"

Comment: I updated to eslint-plugin-prettier 5 and my svelte kit project now has dozens of errors when I run eslint: `Parsing error: '>' expected` in every single svelte file

Comment: I fixed this my changing `extends` in my eslint config to `'eslint:recommended', 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended', 'prettier'` by removing `'plugin:svelte/recommended'`

Answer (score 44):

In my case, the issue was connected with `pretty-quick` tool I used for pre-commit formatting. Current version (pretty-quick v3.1.3) is not compatible with prettier v3, they have an issue in their repo ([link](https://github.com/azz/pretty-quick/issues/164)). And sine the last update of pretty-quick was made 2 years ago, I decided to switch to `lint-staged` which is compatible with prettier v3 and seems to be more live/maintainable (the last release was made 1 week ago). The transition was super easy, just following the readme doc: https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged.

Comment: Thx for the right answer in my case!

Comment: The underlying issue is that Prettier removed the "resolveConfig.sync" API in v3: https://prettier.io/blog/2023/07/05/3.0.0.html

Comment: They've now updated the pretty-quick to 4.0.0 which fixes this compatibility issue, although I had to also tweak eslint config.

Answer (score 18):

I solved this by downgrading prettier to version 2.8.8

Answer (score 18):

When downgrading to `prettier@^2.8.0` you have to install `eslint-plugin-prettier@^4.0.0` for prettier & eslint to work

Comment: Thanks, this was the part I was missing. I was attempting to get VSCode's Prettier Eslint plugin working, which [forced me to downgrade](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier/issues/562) to `prettier@2.8.8`, but this then broke linting on the command line because I was still using `eslint-plugin-prettier@^5.0.0`

Comment: thanks it works with VSCode ESLint+Prettier plugin

Answer (score 7):

Fixing my issue was simpler and the error was a red herring.

I included all the eslint plugins but forgot to actually include prettier itself.

yarn

```
yarn add -D prettier
```

npm

```
npm i -D prettier
```

Hope this helps someone else before they get stuck. Thankfully I realized it quickly.

Answer (score 7):

In my case i was updating `"eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.0"` to `"5.0"` without also updating `prettier`

Answer (score 2):

Using CRA 4.3
I solved it like this
npm i this 3:

```
"eslint": "^7.32.0",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
"prettier": "^2.8.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty stubborn one.
Upgrade to alpha version.

Get more insights here: https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier/issues/562